# Perl retrieve index of array on regex match and print

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, hash

I am looking to extract columns based off of header names in a comma (or tab) delimited file.  I have a scalar variable that matches many header possibilities I named '$Acct_Name', among ones.  I want to read the file(column headers), match it to what I have in '$Acct_Name' and print the matched column along with its data etc.

**Here is my code:**

```
open(FILE, "list_2.txt") or die "Cannot open file: $!";
my $Account_Name = qr/^Acct ID$|^Account No$|^Account$|^ACCOUNT NUMBER$|Account Number|Account.*?Number|^Account$|^Account #$|^Account_ID$|^Account ID$/i;
my $CLIENT = qr/^CLIENT_NAME$|^Account Long Name$|^ACCOUNT NAME$|^Account Name$|^Name$|portfolio.*?description|^Account Description$/i;

while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split(/,/, $line);
    my %index;
    @index{@array} = (0..$#array);
    my $Account_Name_ = $index{$Account_Name};
    if (my ($matched) = grep $array[$_] =~  /$Account_Name/, 0..$#array) {
        $Account_Name_ = $matched;
        my $CLIENT_ = $index{$CLIENT};
        if (my ($matched) = grep $array[$_] =~  /$CLIENT/, 0..$#array) {
            $CLIENT_ = $matched;
            print $array[$Account_Name_],",",$array[$CLIENT_],"\n";
        }
    }
}

close(FILE);
```

**Data, list_2.txt**

Account number,order_num,Name
dj870-1234,12334566,josh trust 1992

**My Results**

Account number,Name

**Desried Out**

Account number,Name
dj870-1234,josh

For some reason I am only able to print the column names based on the match.  How can I grab the data as well?

Comment: Just a note: You don't need to use anchors in every alternation. You can use a non-capturing group to group your expressions. e.g `qr/^(?:Acct ID|Account(?: No)?)$/i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your print statement to output your data lines - these do not match, so in the original code the print statement is never reached !

```
use warnings;

open(FILE, "list_2.txt") or die "Cannot open file: $!";
my $Account_Name = qr/^Acct ID$|^Account No$|^Account$|^ACCOUNT NUMBER$|Account Number|Account.*?Number|^Account$|^Account #$|^Account_ID$|^Account ID$/i;
my $CLIENT = qr/^CLIENT_NAME$|^Account Long Name$|^ACCOUNT NAME$|^Account Name$|^Name$|portfolio.*?description|^Account Description$/i;

my ($Account_Name_, $CLIENT_);
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split(/,/, $line);
    if (my ($matched) = grep $array[$_] =~  /$Account_Name/, 0..$#array) {
        $Account_Name_ = $matched;
        if (my ($matched) = grep $array[$_] =~  /$CLIENT/, 0..$#array) {
            $CLIENT_ = $matched;
        }
    }
    print $array[$Account_Name_],",",$array[$CLIENT_],"\n";
}

close(FILE);
```

Comment: I am getting warnings, "Use of uninitialized value $Account_Name_ in array element at ......" @collapsar

Comment: What does your data look like? do you have additional code in your perl script? I didn't receive the warnings using your code + the 2 line list_2.txt file.

Comment: I'm guessing you didnt get warnings etc. because I left out use strict; use warnings; in my script.  But I am getting warnings and the output is only producing Account number,Account number
dj870-1234,dj870-1234.  Otherwise is close. @collapsar

Comment: oh of course!! my ($Account_Name_, $CLIENT_);  Thanks for the tips!!  @collapsar